# How to release object after drag-drop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I found this interesting example for a javascript Drag/Drop on https://codepen.io/islempenywis/pen/VXqJVY.

However, there is an issue with it that if you click on the top of the "TODO Item" rectangle, after drag (MouseDown + Drag + MouseUp) it is not possible to drop this item; it sticks to the cursor and travels with it :/

MouseUp is a simple function, nothing fancy :

```
function onMouseUp(e, item) {
  isMouseDown = false;
  item.style.backgroundColor = "#F44336";
}
```

Since I can replicate it with Chrome, Edge and Firefox, I am guessing that this is a code problem but can't find out what that would be.

Please help.
Geo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a miscalculation in the `onMouseMove` event handler:

```
item.style.top = e.clientY + mouseOffset.y + "px";
```

When you move the mouse while holding the "TODO" item, the top of the whole element, including its margin, is being placed on the vertical coordinate of the viewport (`e.clientY`) where you clicked and adjusted to the point **in** the element where you clicked (`+ mouseOffset.y`), so the element moves along with the cursor. But it is ignoring its margin. If you pay attention, when you click and move the item, it will move down slightly. Those are 10 pixels of margin. When you click on the top, the element will be placed slightly down the cursor, the cursor will *lose* it, and it gets bugged. To fix, you have to substract the margin in the calculation.

```
item.style.top = e.clientY - 10 + mouseOffset.y + "px";
```

Comment: Wow, that really helped to solve the problem !! I did not know that margins would be part of this calculation. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Yet, I prefer to change this "hard-coded" solution to a better model; is there a way to connect the css parameters to javascript ? item.style.margin parameters seem to be all empty :/

Comment: I found this solution, not scalable to all types but at least an option.`code` let tmpStyle = getComputedStyle(item);
        let strMarginTop = tmpStyle.marginTop;
        let tmpMarginTop = strMarginTop.replace("px", "");
        item.style.top = e.clientY - tmpMarginTop + mouseOffset.y + "px";`code`